# Create folder in Android on Nexus 5

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio, mkdir

This question is duplicate or triplicate, but I can't create a folder!
I've read other questions on this site.
I have added the permission in the manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        package="com.example.val.scemo">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>`
```

My code is this (I tried everything, I have copied the code from the answers on this site):

```
File logFile = new File(LOG_PATH);
boolean a = false;
a = logFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
Log.d("Creare: ", "Directory creata? " + a);
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "TollCulator");
boolean success = true;
if (!folder.exists()) {
    Log.d("Creare: ", "Riprovo ");
    success = folder.mkdir();
    Log.d("Creare: ", "Fatto ");
}
if (success) {
    Log.d("Creare: ", "Cartella creata!1 ");
    // Do something on success
} else {
    Log.d("Creare: ", "FAIL1 ");
    // Do something else on failure
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Example");
boolean success1 = true;
if (!folder.exists()) {
    success1 = folder.mkdirs();
}
if (success1) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("Creare: ", "Cartella creata!2 ");
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("Creare: ", "FAIL2 ");
}
```

All fails. Where am I wrong?
Sorry for my English.

Comment: Are you getting an exception or is the code executing and you can't find the file?

Comment: When the code executing i can't find the folder/directory.

Comment: I have tried this code
File file = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + "FolderName");
if (!file.isDirectory ()) {
    file.mkdirs();
}
but don't work.

Comment: I tried another source code from another project to work properly, but on my Nexus 5 does not create the folder.
The code is this:
private static string logFilePath = null;
logFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "SleepMonitorLogs" + File.separator + "blablafile.txt";


        File logFile = new File(logFilePath);
        boolean a = false;
        a = logFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        Log.d("DIRECTORY ", "CREATA? " + a);


My Nexus 5 is upgraded to 6.0, no root, no changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
File file = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + "FolderName");
if (!file.isDirectory ()) {
    file.mkdirs();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION
I have changed a version of sdk target, from 23 to 21.
Now there is another error:
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
in build.grandle in the line:
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
i have restored at sdk 23 i have sync the project and now working properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to Runtime Permission in Android 6.0 Marshmallow. **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** falls under dangerous permissions list. We need to check permission before every read/write operation.

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

For requesting permissions at runtime checkout these links :
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Arpit Patel has explained it very well here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37358852/5460053

And your are not getting any exception as **File.mkdir()** and **File.mkdirs()** does not throw IOException on failure.

Excerpt from the docs :
[image: File.mkdir() does not throw IOException]

More details : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdir()